# Solving Schrödinger equation analytically to study Bloch waves

Tags: schroedinger-equation, differential-equations

Through solving Schrödinger equation for a periodic potential like $V(x)$ with period $b$ and symmetric about $x=0$, we denote the solution of Schrödinger eq. by two independent wavefunctions called $\psi_{1}(x,E)$ and $\psi_{2}(x,E)$. The Schrödinger equation and initial conditions are given as following:
$$ -\frac {d^{2}\psi} {dx^{2}} + V(x) \psi = E \psi $$
and
$$ \psi_{1}(0,E) = 1 , \psi_{1}^{\prime}(0,E) = 0 $$
$$ \psi_{2}(0,E) = 0 , \psi_{2}^{\prime}(0,E) = 1 . $$
We are looking for solutions of Schrödinger eq. which are multiplied with a constant factor $\lambda$. $$\psi(x+b) = \lambda \psi(x).$$
Then we can tell that if we substitute $\psi=\alpha\psi_{1} + \beta\psi_{2} $ in last restrictive equation while $x$ is set to $0$, then we may write:
$$ \lambda^{2} - \lambda[\psi_{1}(b) + \psi_{2}^{\prime}(b)]     + \psi_{2}^{\prime}(b) \psi_{1}(b) -\psi_{2}(b)\psi_{1}^{\prime}(b) =0 $$
This is what I got by replacing $\psi$ in following equations:
$$\psi(b) = \lambda \psi(0),$$
$$\psi^{\prime}(b)= \lambda \psi^{\prime}(0). $$
But in the [paper](http://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.115.809) the solved equation is given by:
$$ \lambda^{2} - \lambda[\psi_{1}(b) + \psi_{2}^{\prime}(b)] + 1 =0 $$
which means the last part is equal to $1$. But I can not see it!?
$$  \psi_{2}^{\prime}(b) \psi_{1}(b) -\psi_{2}(b)\psi_{1}^{\prime}(b) = 1 $$
I'm feeling so stupid. Please someone helps me :)

Answer (score 3):

That's the Wronksian of the differential equation. If you differentiate it, with some minor manipulations you should find that it is constant, so you can relate its value anywhere to the known value at the initial point.

Comment: Thank you Emilio. It was really helpful. Sometimes I get stuck in some points which makes me embarrassed.

Comment: No worries. Remember that "simple" doesn't always mean "easy" - in fact, most often, quite the opposite! This is a nontrivial observation and there's nothing to be embarrassed about.